# Implementing the builder pattern in python

Tags: python, software-design, solid-principles

I have been studying design patterns. I am struggling with finding a scenario that I can implement builder pattern for that scenario. Has anyone got any example in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, we are going to build a computer for our AppleFactory which would look like the below code without a design pattern (Builder pattern in this case).

```
MINI14 = '1.4GHz Mac mini'


class AppleFactory:
    class MacMini14:
        def __init__(self):
            self.memory = 4  # in gigabytes
            self.hdd = 500  # in gigabytes
            self.gpu = 'Intel HD Graphics 5000'

        def __str__(self):
            info = (f'Model: {MINI14}',
                    f'Memory: {self.memory}GB',
                    f'Hard Disk: {self.hdd}GB',
                    f'Graphics Card: {self.gpu}')
            return '\n'.join(info)

    def build_computer(self, model):
        if model == MINI14:
            return self.MacMini14()
        else:
            msg = f"I don't know how to build {model}"
            print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    afac = AppleFactory()
    mac_mini = afac.build_computer(MINI14)
    print(mac_mini)
```

Let's use the Builder design pattern to decouple the above code.

```
class Computer:
    def __init__(self, serial_number):
        self.serial = serial_number
        self.memory = None # in gigabytes
        self.hdd = None # in gigabytes
        self.gpu = None
    def __str__(self):
        info = (f'Memory: {self.memory}GB',
                f'Hard Disk: {self.hdd}GB',
                f'Graphics Card: {self.gpu}')
        return '\n'.join(info)

class ComputerBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.computer = Computer('AG23385193')
    def configure_memory(self, amount):
        self.computer.memory = amount
    def configure_hdd(self, amount):
        self.computer.hdd = amount
    def configure_gpu(self, gpu_model):
        self.computer.gpu = gpu_model

class HardwareEngineer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = None
    def construct_computer(self, memory, hdd, gpu):
        self.builder = ComputerBuilder()
        steps = (self.builder.configure_memory(memory),
        self.builder.configure_hdd(hdd),
        self.builder.configure_gpu(gpu))
        [step for step in steps]

    @property
    def computer(self):
        return self.builder.computer

def main():
    engineer = HardwareEngineer()
    engineer.construct_computer(hdd=500,memory=8,gpu='GeForce GTX 650 Ti')
    computer = engineer.computer
    print(computer)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here, we have decoupled our code into 3 classes - Computer, ComputerBuilder, and HardwareEngineer such that anyone can just call HardwareEngineer class and build.

- [builder design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder/python/example)